# Are unused imports acceptable if they run a function on import?

Tags: python, import

I use a lot of different basic scripts to push data around at different times, pull reports, etc. These have a cron entry to run on a VM.

When each of these scripts starts, I want to run a function which is shared. However my current way of doing this feels unclear.

A basic example, I have:

`sharedmodule.py`:

```
def script_start_func()
    # do stuff

script_start_func()
```

and then I import this module into each of the scripts that are running, so that the function is run when the module is imported, like so:

`one_of_many_different_scripts.py`:

```
import sharedmodule  #flagged in IDE as unused

# do normal script stuff
```

It feels like there should be a better way of achieving the same end, although at the time it seemed like a reasonable way of not requiring `sharedmodule.script_start_func()` at the top of every script.

Is there a preferred way of actioning this?

I'm starting to think that actually calling the function is only one extra line and is clear as to what is happening?

I've searched for this topic but can't seem to find an existing answer.

Thanks

Comment: Then have something else run that script, don't force your code to have to invoke it.

Comment: "When each of these scripts starts, I want to run a function " Then calling the function when the script starts looks like the right thing to do. What are you worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer by quoting from "The Zen of Python":

```
> python -c "import this"
```

> The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Complex is better than complicated.
>   Flat is better than nested.
>   Sparse is better than dense.
>   Readability counts.
>   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.
>   Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
>   Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
>   If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
>   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

The second line states that *Explicit is better than implicit.* and that is what I want to communicate. Explicitly calling the function is much better than implicit for a few reasons:

- It gives you control when and where that function gets called
- It helps with debugging when things go wrong because you have the ability to comment out the call, print some debugging information before and/or after that call
- The code is easier to understand because that call is not hidden in your calling script

The cost for this is of course, having to type one extra line, but I believe the benefits out weight the cost.